# Why is ConceptNet Numberbatch word embedding giving poor results for analogy queries?

Tags: stanford-nlp, word-embedding, conceptnet

I've been playing around with analogy queries over some publicly available word embeddings, in particular using the following:

- `numberbatch-en-19.08` from https://github.com/commonsense/conceptnet-numberbatch
- `glove.42B.300d` from https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/
- `glove.840B.300d` from https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/

I'm doing some basic queries that include (where `queryTarget` is what I am looking for):

`baseSource:baseTarget :: querySource:queryTarget`
e.g. `man:woman :: king:queen`

- maximize `cosine_similarity(baseTarget-baseSource, queryTarget-querySource)`
- maximize `cosine_similarity(baseTarget-baseSource, queryTarget-querySource) * cosine_similarity(baseTarget-queryTarget,baseSource-querySource)`
- minimize L2norm(baseTarget-baseSource+querySource, queryTarget)

For the query:
`man:woman :: king:?`

The `glove` data gives me the correct `queen`, `lady`, `princess` results for the various matching strategies. However, conceptnet gives `female_person`, `adult_female`, `king_david's_harp` as top 3, which I would not expect (queen is not in the top 20). Similarly, I see poor results regularly displace expected results that I do see in the glove results.

Does the conceptnet embedding require some sort of additional tweaking before I can use it? Or is it just not tailored/suited for English analogies?

Comment: Good question. I'm finding the same thing in that conceptnet numberbatch has strange things going on. Could it be to do with the weightings that they've introduced? (Described on github)?